# Can Alexa routines run arbitrary commands?

Tags: alexa, amazon-echo

I have some skills that require quite a long phrase to activate (eg. "Alexa, tell Smart Remote to turn on my TV"), but it seems quite redundant for me to repeat this, when I'll be using the same skill every time for this task.

I would rather say something shorter like "Alexa, turn on my TV", and activate other skills in the same fashion.

I wondered if [Alexa routines](https://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html?nodeId=202200080) could help here, but I could only see how to add "News", "Smart Home", "Traffic" or "Weather" actions. Instead, I'd like to be able to run any skill from a routine (ideally, I'd just like to type in what I would have said, and let Alexa run that at the correct time).

Is this possible, or am I limited to using the few available options for actions?

Comment: Your remote and/or TV don’t show up under Smart Home? You may be out of luck for native Alexa usage, although I’d look into Yonomi, Stringify, and/or IFTTT. There are almost certainly workarounds if there’s actually is a hole in support in this instance.

Comment: Which smart remote are you using?

Answer (score 3):

This *might* work.

1. Create a new routine activated by voice command
2. Under “Actions” for the routine, select “Custom”
3. Type “tell Smart Remote to turn on my TV”
4. Use the “Preview this action” feature and select your smart speaker.